# How to make this inheritance work in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

How can we compile the below code without changing the class b?

```
class a {
    public a(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public b(int x) {
        //super(x);
    }        
}
```

Comment: If you can't change the class b, change the class a. The error message you get from the compiler tells you what the problem is. Read it.

Comment: Just declare a no-arg constructor in `class a`.

Comment: Without declaring the default constructor in class.. is there any other way to resolve this problem. Becoz. one of my friend asking this doubt me.

Comment: Someone continuously reducing my point. this type of behaviour discourage me.

Comment: I have seen the below answers in eclipse's error tips itself.

Comment: I have told samething to my friend too. but he is expecting some what new solution.

Comment: Your *friend* eh? Does he go by the name of Teacher or Professor per chance?

Comment: "I have seen the below answers in eclipse's error tips itself" ok why not point that out in the question? This "friend" I assume is the one who set the homework. You didn't specify what you wanted, you got correct answers based on the information given...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but to get it compile, simply add implicit constructor to class `a`:

```
class a {

    public a(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public a() {
        // implicit constructor
    }
}
```

Since `b` extends `a` and doesn't call the super constructor, implicit constructor of `a` is called "behind the scene". Therefore `a` must provide one.

Comment: I know that.. if we have explicit constructor in any class.. that will overtake the default implicit constructor.

Comment: Just I am asking the other possiblities.

Comment: There are no other possibilities, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you need to add a zero argument constructor in the parent class and the code will start compiling fine.

```
class a {
public a() {
}
public a(int x) {
    System.out.println(x);
}

}

class b extends a {

public b(int x) {
    //super(x);
}

}
```

Comment: Why are these solutions being downvoted? It is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

When subclass extends super class if there is no constructor written it takes default constructor. But, if any constructor written in a class compiler won't keep default constructor. It is necessary to have default constructor when subclass inherits super class because for inheritance compiler will always first go to super class constructor and then subclass constructor. For ex:

If we have

```
class A{
}
class B extends A{
}
```

We do not need to write constructor. Compiler will take default constructor.

But if we have

```
class A{
    public A(double i){
    }

}
class B extends A{
     public B(double j){
     }
}
```

In this situation we need to write explicit default constructor for super class.